# Compile boost-python 1.73.0 for Windows with MinGW64 on Fedora

Tags: boost, mingw, cross-compiling, boost-python, mingw-w64

I need to compile boost-python 1.73.0 with MinGW64 on Fedora's rawhide, so that I can build Python bindings for Windows 10 64bit (no, I can't use Visual Studio unfortunately). And unfortunately the only library missing from Fedora's `mingw64-boost` package is `boost-python`, argggh!

Actually all dependencies are packaged on Fedora for MinGW64, which is quite nice. So I'm trying to build myself with:

```
wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.73.0/source/boost_1_73_0.tar.bz2
tar -xjf boost_1_73_0.tar.bz2 && cd boost_1_73_0
./bootstrap.sh
# in a docker container, so /root
./b2 --with-python address-model=64 target-os=windows toolset=gcc-mingw64 \
     variant=release link=shared --user-config=/root/user-config.jam
```

And a `~/user-config.jam`:

```
using gcc : mingw64 : x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ ;

using python
     : 3.9
     : /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/python3.9.exe
     : /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/python3.9
     : /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/python3.9 ;
```

It runs for a while successfully, but then errors out on

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lutil
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So `libutil` is missing somehow. What a super specific name! I tried (re-)installing all glibc packages (where libutil.so apparently usually is in), to no avail. Also found a `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libutildll.a`, tried including it via `./b2 library=...`, again no luck.

What's going on here? BTW, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nilsnolde/4f8e066fd8dfa257cda184a480e14da1) has the full command which is failing.

Answer (score 0):

So, this needed a patch to the boost sources to get rid of the `libutil` linking. To compile fully, a batch of other patch files had to be applied. Here's my full command chain in fedora:rawhide:

1. Get the sources

```
wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.73.0/source/boost_1_73_0.tar.bz2
tar -xjf boost_1_73_0.tar.bz2
cd boost_1_73_0
```

2. Setup `~/user-config.jam`

```
cat >> ~/user-config.jam <<EOL
using gcc : mingw64 : x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ ;

using python
     : 3.9
     : /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/python3.9
     : /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/python3.9
     : /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/python3.9/config-3.9 ;
EOL
```

3. Bootstrap boost

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-icu=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/ --with-toolset=gcc
```

4. Patch all files in `./boost_1_73_0_patches` from

- the single patch in this repo (git clone for source): https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mingw-w64-boost-python/
- all patch files from this repo: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-boost

Mostly apply like this:

```
patch -p1 -i patches/boost-1.63.0-python-test-PyImport_AppendInittab.patch
```

5. Build boost-python

```
./b2 address-model=64 link=shared runtime-link=shared threading=multi threadapi=win32 toolset=gcc variant=release python=3.9 --with-python
```